# Display formula problem

Tags: configuration

[image]

Hello all,
I use Mathematica for several years without any problem.

But since last week, I can't write correctly formulas on Mathematica. For a simple example, if I write $\frac{1}{2}$ by typing $1  /2$ , a small retangular appears instead of the operator $/$.

And if I declare a CDF of the normal distribution, I just got an unreadable formula.

I don't know why. Perhaps because I has modified the Windows system last month?

Do you have any idea to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe some font files missing.

Comment: You probably need help from Wolfram Support.

Comment: @cvgmt & MArcoB : Thank you all.

Comment: I decide to reinstall Mathematica and it works now.